# Android TV with Jetpack compose visitAncestors called on an unattached node

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-tv

Help to solve issue Android tv with jetpack compose some time application crash and give error like **"java.lang.IllegalStateException: visitAncestors called on an unattached node"** error logcat

java.lang.IllegalStateException: visitAncestors called on an unattached node
at androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusTargetNode.fetchFocusProperties$ui_release(FocusTargetNode.kt:251)
at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.searchChildren-4C6V_qg(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:170)
at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.generateAndSearchChildren-4C6V_qg(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:141)
at androidx.compose.ui.focus.TwoDimensionalFocusSearchKt.searchChildren-4C6V_qg(TwoDimensionalFocusSearch.kt:173)

Comment: Can you paste code which is causing this issue? It will help debug. There seems to be an existing bug about this: [b/312677265](https://issuetracker.google.com/312677265)

Comment: it will happen when multiple click dpad key action press, like 2 left and then after 3 bottom and then after 2 up side. so application was crash randomly.